# Bootstrap's button.js and Turbolinks issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, turbolinks

The custom CSS class `.btn-loading` disables the button and sets its text to loading state:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-loading', function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.button('loading');

    // Fail-safe for buttons that get stuck in the loading state sometimes.
    setTimeout(function() {
        Rollbar.error("Button stuck");
        btn.button('reset');
    }, 10000);
});

// Be sure to remove any loading state on page refresh
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
    $('.btn-loading').button('reset');
});
```

Example button

```
button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-loading" data-loading-text="Processing..." Continue
```

When the button is pressed, text is changed to 'Processing...' and the button is disabled preventing multiple submits.

However, sometimes in development and production, the button gets stuck in the loading state and for some reason does not cause the submit and/or rendering of the new page. The `setTimeout` is firing multiple times a day on the production server. We are having hard times producing the problem on the development consistently.. it happens randomly now and then.

Rollbar's statistics shows that it's not browser specific nor a single button+action that's causing it. So the cause is not a slow server response either.

Any idea what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: What does you javascript do after the `loading` is triggered?  This operation may be failing or not returning correctly.

Comment: Where in the document are you putting this script? I've seen issues like this related to having script tags inside the <body> of a Turbolinks app.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem some time back and solved the same with a different approach. Try to follow the below steps to solve your problem.

HTML:

Change your button type from “Submit” to “Button”. This will give you full control to execute your scripts.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id=”SubmitButton”>Submit</button>
```

JQUERY:

On Button Click, you need to disable the button. This will immediately stop users to click again. Then you can change the button text to "Processing". Below script will guide you make it happen.

```
$(function () {

    $('#SubmitButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //Disable Button to avoid multiple clicks
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);

       // Change the button text to “Processing”
       $(this).text(‘Processing’);

       // Write Your Validation Scripts
       // If Validation Fails - $(this).text(‘Submit’); $(this).attr("disabled", '');
       // Else Submit Form

       //Submit the Form
       $("#targetForm").submit();

    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent multiple submit you can use $.one() function also. and add remaining logic.

Answer (score 1):

> When the button is pressed, text is changed to 'Processing...' and the
>   button is disabled preventing multiple submits.

-- Note that there's not part in your code snippet that disables the button.

```
// Fail-safe for buttons that get stuck in the loading state sometimes.
setTimeout(function() {
    // if(stuck){
    Rollbar.error("Button stuck");
    btn.button('reset');
    // } // end-if
}, 10000);
```

-- It looks like your fallback will always be executed. Shouldn't be executed when the button is stuck?

> The setTimeout is firing multiple times a day on the production
>   server.

-- Because your button is never disabled, and because there is no condition restricting it from firing on being clicked.

Moreover, there's no jQuery method like `button()`. It looks like you're using jQueryUI, which you should have mentioned as well. But jQueryUI + Bootstrap seem like a weird combination, to me.